# Integrate MPU6050 with Windows 10 IoT (windows.devices.sensors)

Tags: uwp, raspberry-pi, windowsiot, windows-iot-core-10, mpu6050

I am currently working with Windows 10 IoT and RaspberryPi 3b + MPU6050 connected over I2C.

While looking around I found windows.devices.sensors.accelerometer and windows.devices.sensors.gyrometer.
I think these classes can be used on Windows Phones to access Sensorreadings, so I was wondering:

Is it possible to integrate my MPU6050 sensor-boards accelerometer and gyroscope to work with these classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To connect MPU6050 with Windows IoT Core via I2C you can refer to "[Windows 10: How to use IoT extension for Raspberry Pi 2 (part 2)](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/cdndevs/2015/05/15/windows-10-how-to-use-iot-extension-for-raspberry-pi-2-part-2/)" and "[MPU6050 Accelerometer on Windows 10 Raspberry 2](https://www.hackster.io/vityushenka/mpu6050-accelerometer-on-windows-10-raspberry-2-afcdae)".

If you want to check windows.devices.sensors.accelerometer API work or not you can refer to "[UWP sample - Accelerometer sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/Accelerometer)". But to use these API the sensor need be supported. You may need related driver.

> The driver for a sensor must indicate that the hardware is integrated
>   with the PC chassis for it to be accessible via this namespace.
>   Sensors not marked as PC-integrated, even if they are of a supported
>   type, will not be accessible. Driver developers can refer to
>   SensorConnectionType enumeration for more details. ([Windows.Devices.Sensors Namespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.sensors#remarks))

Comment: Do you know where to find the related driver?

Comment: @Stephan You can contact the MPU reseller to see if they can provide a driver. It is suggested to use Windows.Devices.I2c API to control the MPU. It is more simple to implement.